# searching and selecting the area around a cell in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select, search

I have been using pandas for work lately and I am fairly new to it. I have a data frame and I wanted to search the whole data frame for a specific string and then select the *n* cells to the right and to the left of it. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this dummy input, we'll be looking for `0` as target with `n=2` values on the left/right:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[10,10]))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  5  0  3  3  7  9  3  5  2  4
1  7  6  8  8  1  6  7  7  8  1
2  5  9  8  9  4  3  0  3  5  0
3  2  3  8  1  3  3  3  7  0  1
4  9  9  0  4  7  3  2  7  2  0
5  0  4  5  5  6  8  4  1  4  9
6  8  1  1  7  9  9  3  6  7  2
7  0  3  5  9  4  4  6  4  4  3
8  4  4  8  4  3  7  5  5  0  1
9  5  9  3  0  5  0  1  2  4  2
```

processing:

```
n = 2

# get target as mask
mask = df.eq(0)

#generate a mask
mask2 = mask.astype(int).rolling(2*n+1, min_periods=1, center=True, axis=1).sum().gt(0)

# select cells
# here it's unclear what you want to do
# so as example let's mask the non-match cells
df.where(mask2, '-')
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  5  0  3  3  -  -  -  -  -  -
1  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
2  -  -  -  -  4  3  0  3  5  0
3  -  -  -  -  -  -  3  7  0  1
4  9  9  0  4  7  -  -  7  2  0
5  0  4  5  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
6  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
7  0  3  5  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
8  -  -  -  -  -  -  5  5  0  1
9  -  9  3  0  5  0  1  2  -  -
```